# How to use StreamProvider with minimal widget re-build and firestore read?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, provider

I want to `StreamProvider` to pass my `UserData` object through out all the widgets, so it can be accessible anywhere.

The `UserData` object is taken/read from the Firestore database.

My questions are:

1. How can I use StreamProvider properly/efficiently so it will minimize the widget rebuild and read from Firestore (cause Firebase bills per every document read, CMIIW)?
2. Should I use FutureProvider instead? But I want the UI also be able to be updated when there is change in the database.

Answer (score 1):

With Provider, you can use Consumer and Selector to avoid unnecessarily rebuilds.

https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/